# More precise formula for small deviations of the Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes

The following first order asymptotics is well-known: $P(\|W\|_\infty < r)=\exp\{-\frac{\pi^2}{8 r^2}(1+o(1))\}$ as $r\to 0$, where $W$ is the Wiener process on [0,1].

Has anybody met an exact formula for $P(\|W\|_\infty < r)=?$ (for arbitrary $0<r<1$) or at least more precise asymptotics (the second or the third order)?

Answer (score 2):

See formula (7.15) on p.218 of Mörters-Peres "Brownian motion" (it is better suited for the case $r\to 0$ than (7.14) of Theorem 7.45 there).

Comment: Is there similar exact formula for the centered Poisson process to stay within an interval?

Comment: Thank you, that's what was needed! It seems that the next order after $r^{−2}$ is a constant.

Comment: Не за что!  For the centered Poisson process, I don't know...  maybe, use the KMT strong approximation to be able to use the same formula?..